# Tool to format MATLAB code

Tags: software-development, code-beautification, matlab

To the [best of my knowledge](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/289303-does-matlab-have-the-function-to-format-script) one can't script MATLAB's editor to apply code formatting to a file; one has to actually open the file in the editor, select the full text and press a key combo.

Obviously, this kind of makes Matlab the least favorite of my tools, as I can't even do a script that works through 10 years of my predecessors writing code, nor can have any tooling (git hooks, CI servers...) that checks/improves formatting to attain a basic level of code hygiene.

Is there any proven tool that can do at least rudimentary code formatting?

Hard requirements:

- Proper indenting of code, comments
- Consisten spacing around operators, in argument lists
- Runs on Linux
- Comes free for someone who has Matlab
- CLI tool, i.e. possible to use from scripts, or Python module, or C or C++ library

It specifically *does not* have to be part of matlab (although it would be very desirable if matlab auto-indent and the tool would agree).

I've tried my vim and emacs installations, `astyle` and whatnot, but they can't deal with m-code.

Comment: I've never tried it, but maybe Emacs: https://sourceforge.net/projects/matlab-emacs/ Also, Atom seems to have some support: https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=✓&q=keyword:matlab

Comment: @EricS I've got emacs, but rudimentary indenting is all it can do. Atom, I didn't try, but it's not useful for formatting from scripts, as far as I know?

Comment: As I said, I've never tried it and I no longer use MATLAB. The link to Atom look more promising perhaps. The link I gave gets cut off but there are at least 8 Atom packages associated with MATLAB integration. I think Atom is scriptable: https://atom.io/packages/script

Comment: @EricS I've checked these, but none are actually useful for anyone trying to format code non-interactively. It's nice that you can run scripts from within Atom, but that doesn't mean I can instrumentalize Atom externally.

Comment: Sorry I can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest https://github.com/florianschanda/miss_hit :)

There are several tools in this suite, but one of them (mh_style) can auto-format code. I believe this tool fulfils all of your criteria above.